# Make text bold, italic or underline while writing in edittext

Tags: android, html, android-edittext

I want my editText to able to write text in bold, italic and underline along with normal text.

Eg:

The **weather** is ***nice*** *today*.

I know I can use html tags but I want to perform these operations while writing in the edittext.

What I have tried:

```
 //here textEdits is my model to store the string. As I have multiple editTexts in the activity.
 @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                if(isBold){
                    String textsequence = textEdits.get(position).getTextString();
                    if(i > 0){
                            String sequence = charSequence.subSequence(0, i).toString() +"<b>"+ charSequence.subSequence(i,i+i3).toString() + "</b>";
                            textEdits.get(position).setTextString(sequence.toString());
                            editTextcurrrent.setText(Html.fromHtml(sequence.toString()));
                            editTextcurrrent.setSelection(i+i3);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    textEdits.get(position).setTextString(charSequence.toString());
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem:
The charSequence returns a string without html tags so, once you have set the value, the next time you will get a string without html tags, and therefore you cannot track your previous html edits.

Other than this I have tried Typeface but even that didn't work out. 
Also apologies if the work that I tried is not quite understandable, Its a part of a large code so there are quite a lot linked up and I tried to remove  as much dependencies as I could.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use SpannableString:

```
String yourString = "The weather is nice today."
SpannableString contentSpan = new SpannableString(yourString);
contentSpan.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(activity, R.style.bold_style), weatherFirstPos, weatherLastPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
contentSpan.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(activity, R.style.italic_style), niceFirstPos, niceLastPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editTextcurrrent.setText(contentSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

For R.style.bold_style and italic_style you can have something like:

```
<style name="bold_style">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

weatherFirstPos, weatherLastPos, niceFirstPos and niceLastPos are the positions of where you want to apply the style:

```
int weatherFirstPos = yourString.indexOf("weather");
int weatherLastPos = weatherFirstPos + "weather".length();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use OnFocusChange Listener & Change EditText properties as you like when EditText gain focus of user

or

you can also set in Xml bold and italic.

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                android:text="enter your name"/>
```

Comment: But this will make the whole text bold|italic. Not just part of it.

Comment: this will make whole text bold. Please read the question properly before answering

Comment: @Adrian-AlexandruComan ,u can use SpannableString , for customizing some portion in paragraph.